# Radius of Convergence of $\sum_n \frac{z^{2n}}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem (exercise) is to find radius of Convergence of $\sum_n \frac{z^{2n}}{n}$. The way I proceed was: put $z^{2}=w$. Then the series is $\sum_n \frac{w^n}{n}$, which (I know) converges if $|w|<1$ and diverges if $|w|>1$. Hence the original series converges if $|z|^2<1$ (i.e. $|z|<1$) and diverges if $|z|^2>1$ (i.e. $|z|>1$).

The final answer I think is correct. But, I am not sure whether the substitution $z^2=w$ is allowed here, because they give different functions in complex analysis with some branches, and when defining branches of some function, I should be careful.

**Q.** Is the *method* of substitution correct in the above problem?

Comment: Since the radius of convergence here only depends on $|z|$ it is safe to go between $z$ and $w=z^2$ since $|w|=|z^2|=|z|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. 
Your answer is quite elementary, you just used the definition of the radius of convergence:

$$
R = \sup\{
r>0 : \sum |a_n| r^n < \infty
\}
$$

Comment: sorry! I couldn't touch your answer.