# Confusion about radius of convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{z^{np}}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm supposed to compute the radius of convergence of the complex series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{z^{np}}{n}$, where $p$ is a fixed natural number.

Well, if we call $w = z^p$, then $\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{z^{np}}{n} = \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{w^n}{n}$, and by Hadamard's formula, the radius of convergence is: $$\rho = \frac{1}{\limsup\sqrt[n]{1/n}} = 1,$$so that the series converges for $|w| < 1$, that is, the original series converges for the numbers $z \in \Bbb C$ such that $|z|^p < 1$. The substituition seems valid (e.g., [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101055/radius-of-convergence-of-sum-n-fracz2nn)). Also, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=radius+of+convergence+sum+z%5E%7Bnp%7D%2Fn) states that we must have $|z^p| \leq 1$ and $z^p \neq 1$.

> **Questions:** Can we make the step $|z|^p < 1 \iff |z| < 1$? Also, why is $|z^p| = 1$ with $z^p \neq 1$ allowed?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, for $p > 0$, $t^p$ is an increasing function of $t$ on $[0,\infty)$ with $1^p = 1$, so $|z|^p < 1$ iff $|z| < 1$.
2. Dirichlet's test.

Comment: Ok for $1$. I went to look Dirichlet's test, but I still don't get it. Okay, using [wiki's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) notation, we would let $a_n = 1/n$, and $a_n \downarrow 0$, ok. But $b_n = |z^{np}| = |(z^p)^n| = |z^p|^n = 1$ does not satisfies $\sum b_n  < M$ for no constant $M$. Also, the fact that $z^p \neq 1$ didn't enter here.

Comment: $b_n = z^{np}$, not $|z^{np}|$.

Answer (score 0):

To explore the convergence of $\sum\frac{w^n}{n}$, multiply with $w-1$ to get
$$
(w-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{w^n}{n}
=-w+w·\sum_{n=1}^∞\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)·w^n
=-w+w·\sum_{n=1}^∞\frac{w^n}{n(n+1)}
$$
which clearly converges absolutely for all $|w|\le 1$. The perform the division to get back to the original series, $w=1$ needs to be excluded.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand. The RHS of the first line is just zero, doesn't seems right to me..